# ember build Parse error on line 1: {{#each messages as |message|}}

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I was attempting to update my ember cli project from ember 1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 & handlebar 1.3.0 -> 2.0.0 however now I get the following error, when I use the command `ember build` :

```
Build failed.
File: ui/templates/components/ember-notify.hbs
Parse error on line 1:
{{#each messages as |message|}}  {{#vie
--------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'EQUALS', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{{#each messages as |message|}}  {{#vie
--------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'EQUALS', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
    at Object.parseError (/Users/shivamsinha/Desktop/Programming/workspace/feedserver/ui/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:106:11)
    at Object.parse (/Users/shivamsinha/Desktop/Programming/workspace/feedserver/ui/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:158:22)
    at HandlebarsEnvironment.parse (/Users/shivamsinha/Desktop/Programming/workspace/feedserver/ui/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/base.js:18:17)
    at TemplateCompiler.EmberHandlebars.precompile (/Users/shivamsinha/Desktop/Programming/workspace/feedserver/ui/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/node_modules/ember-template-compiler/vendor/ember-template-compiler.js:239:24)
    at TemplateCompiler.processString (/Users/shivamsinha/Desktop/Programming/workspace/feedserver/ui/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/index.js:58:38)
    at TemplateCompiler.Filter.processFile (/Users/shivamsinha/Desktop/Programming/workspace/feedserver/ui/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/node_modules/broccoli-filter/index.js:136:31)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for ui goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.0",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^0.2.1",
    "broccoli-static-compiler": "^0.2.1",
    "ember-cli": "^0.1.11",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-cookie": "^0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2": "^0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-torii": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-tooltipster": "0.0.6",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-idx-button": "^0.1.3",
    "ember-idx-forms": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-mousetrap": "0.2.0",
    "ember-notify": "^3.1.4",
    "ember-template-compiler": "^1.9.0-alpha",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5",
    "torii": "^0.3.3"
  }
}
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.9.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.11",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.5",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "ember-addons.bs_for_ember": "~0.7.0",
    "slick.js": "~1.4.0",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "~3.1.12",
    "videojs-youtube": "~1.2.8",
    "tooltipster": "~3.3.0",
    "ember-mousetrap": "~0.2.0",
    "ember-validations": "2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "rsvp": "~3.0.18",
    "bootswatch": "v3.3.4+1",
    "ember-simple-auth": "~0.7.3",
    "progressbar.js": "~0.8.1",
    "selectivity": "~1.1.0",
    "select2": "~4.0.0",
    "select2-bootstrap3-css": "~1.4.6",
    "jquery-mentions": "~1.0.1",
    "jquery-autocomplete": "~1.1.1",
    "owl.carousel": "2.0.0-beta.2.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be using old version of HTMLBars and/or Ember CLI. You should upgrade to Ember CLI `0.2.7` from `^0.1.11`(that's weird you're using ^ here, because upgrading from each version of Ember CLI requires some steps to take) and `ember-cli-htmlbars` to `0.7.6`.

Here's the [valid package.json](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-output/blob/master/package.json) file for latest versions of Ember and [valid bower.json](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-output/blob/master/bower.json).

Check what version of Ember CLI you have installed currently, or please remove it completely, then update important package versions in `package.json`, `bower.json` to valid ones linked before. Then do setup steps and project update steps from [Ember CLI releases site](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases)(clean cache etc.).